# XML processing in JRuby without FFI?

Tags: xml, jruby

What's the best available library right now?

I don't really care about features much, as long as it provides something SAX-like at reasonable performance levels (not REXML).

Answer (score 0):

I've had good luck with [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) on JRuby.  There is a native java backend for the newer versions.